# Imageview not initializing with the correct size

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently programming a little game which has a big field in the middle of it.

The field is displayed with a grid pane which has a stack pane bound to each of its "Cells", on which a canvas is added to later draw the different field types.

The characters are displayed as image views which are added and taken away to move them around the field.

The Problem is after loading(which means reading all the necessary data from a text file) a previously saved game the image view wont fit itself to the stack panes which leads to a distortion of the field.

The following contains the code which initializes the grid pane, stack panes and canvases.

```
    public class RealGUI {@Override
public void createGrid(GridPane grid, int row, int col) {
    this.gridPane = grid;
    System.out.println("col creategrid: " + col);
    System.out.println("row creategrid " + row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        this.gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(0, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE,
                Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        this.gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(0, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE,
                Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
    }
    colcount = gridPane.getColumnConstraints().size();
    rowcount = gridPane.getRowConstraints().size();
    this.stackPane = initImageStackPane();
    initCanvases();
}



private StackPane[][] initImageStackPane() {
    StackPane[][] square = new StackPane[colcount][rowcount];
    // bind each Imageview to a cell of the gridpane
    for (int y = 0; y < colcount; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < rowcount; x++) {
            square[y][x] = new StackPane();
            square[y][x].setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
            square[y][x].setMouseTransparent(true);
            square[y][x].setMinSize(0, 0);
            gridPane.add(square[y][x], y, x);
        }
    }
    return square;
}

private void initCanvases() {
    this.canvas = new ResizableCanvas[colcount][rowcount];
    for (int y = 0; y < colcount; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < rowcount; x++) {
            this.canvas[y][x] = new ResizableCanvas();
            this.canvas[y][x].setMouseTransparent(true);
            this.stackPane[y][x].getChildren().add(this.canvas[y][x]);
            this.canvas[y][x].widthProperty().bind(stackPane[y][x].widthProperty());
            this.canvas[y][x].heightProperty().bind(stackPane[y][x].heightProperty());

        }
    }
}}
```

this is called after the previous code

```
public class EditorBoard{
public void loadField(File file, int ySize, int xSize) throws IOException {
    load = new fileLoader(file, ySize, xSize);
    this.board = load.getBoard();
    this.monsterPosi[0] = load.getMonster().getY();
    this.monsterPosi[1] = load.getMonster().getX();
    this.treasurePosi = load.getTreasurePosi();
    changeGUIafterLoad();
    this.game.uncoverFieldEditor(monsterPosi[1], monsterPosi[0], FieldTypeEnums.MONSTER, false);
}

private void changeGUIafterLoad() {
    for (int y = 0; y < board.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < board[0].length; x++) {
            game.uncoverFieldEditor(x, y, board[y][x].getField(),
                    board[y][x].getEnergyStone());
        }
    }
}



public class RealGUI{
@Override
public void uncoverFieldEditor(int y, int x, FieldTypeEnums fieldType, boolean energy) {
    switch (fieldType) {
        case CAVE:

            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, energy);
            break;
        case FOREST:
            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, energy);
            break;
        case GRAS:
            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, energy);
            break;
        case LIANE:
            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, energy);
            break;
        case MOUNTAIN:
            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, false);
            break;
        case RIVER:
            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, false);
            break;
        case TREASURE:
            this.canvas[y][x].draw(fieldType, false);
            break;
        case MONSTER:
            // imageview with the monster that is moved on the field of the game / editor
            this.mon = new ImageView(imgMonster);
            this.mon.minHeight(0.0);
            this.mon.minWidth(0.0);

            this.mon.setPreserveRatio(false);
            this.mon.setSmooth(true);
            stackPane[y][x].getChildren().add(mon);
            this.mon.fitHeightProperty().bind(stackPane[y][x].heightProperty().multiply(0.7));
            this.mon.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackPane[y][x].widthProperty().multiply(0.7));

        default:
            break;
    }

}
}
```

I'm at a real loss trying to find the cause of this problem. I hope that the provided code snippets are enough to find the problem.

Thank you to anyone who takes their time to look at this.

Comment: If I read the code correctly, the image view will be sized to the containing stack pane, which will fill its cell in the grid pane. So the size of the image view will essentially be determined by the size of the other nodes in the same row and column. I.e. the image will be resized so that it is the full width of the column and full height of the row (and those will be determined, mainly, by what else is in the row and column). Is that what you intend? Is it not what you are seeing?

Comment: thats indeed what is was intending to do and it normally looks like the first picture but when its added via the described way above it ends up like the second one (http://imgur.com/a/uEKnM)

Comment: It looks like you're swapping the X and Y around when you call uncoverFieldEditor(). It expects (y, x), but you call it with (x, y) for both the monster in loadField() and in changeGUIAfterLoad().

Comment: i know thats because the y and x axis are swapped in  RealGUI